# Skype for Business 2015 installed - but where are the clients?

Tags: skype

I've got the following setup

- Skype for Business 2015 Standard running on Windows Server 2016.
- 2 x Windows 10 Creator Update clients.

All seems fine on the server. All services running, I've enabled users on Skype for Business. From the server's point of view, I'm ready.

On the clients, I've installed Office 2016. However, there are no "Skype for Business" client installs. I've found "Skype for Business Basic 2016" on the web, but these don't seem to connect to my server.

Have I got the right clients? Is there a place where I can download the clients from?

I'm surprised no-one else has asked this question, which either means

- the clients are the correct ones, and the configuration is somehow wrong
- there is an obvious place on the server where the client install is (and I haven't seen it...).

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft Skype for Business client is included in:

- Microsoft Office Professional **Plus** 2016 Suite
- Microsoft Office 2013 Pro **Plus** Suite (called Lync here, however if MS office is fully updated it will change to Skype for Business including the "GUI"; more infos [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54108))

Depending on your license agreement you might also wish to use:

- [Microsoft Skype for Business Basic for Windows](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49440) (has limited features!)
- [Skype for Business on Mac](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54108)